# One Signal - idsAvailable is deprecated

Tags: ios, swift, onesignal

OneSignal's latest build version generate a warning like '**idsAvailable**' is deprecated. How can I get 'playerID' using **getPermissionSubscriptionState()** instead idsAvailable as I did below?

```
    OneSignal.idsAvailable({ (userId, pushToken) in

        if (pushToken != nil) {

            if let playerID = userId {

                // do something

            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OneSignal keeps really good documentation.

For android you can get userIDs by using the `idsAvailable` method which returns the userID and registrationID.

userID aka playerID is a OneSignal UUID formatted string. (unique per device per app)
registrationID is a Google assigned identifier (unique per device per app and changes on reinstalls).

For iOS, you can get the userIDs in the same way but in version 2.5.0+ of the native iOS SDK added getPermissionSubscriptionState method and addSubscriptionObserver.

You can get the OSPermissionSubscriptionState for Swift as follows:

```
let status: OSPermissionSubscriptionState = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState()

let hasPrompted = status.permissionStatus.hasPrompted
print("hasPrompted = \(hasPrompted)")
let userStatus = status.permissionStatus.status
print("userStatus = \(userStatus)")

let isSubscribed = status.subscriptionStatus.subscribed
print("isSubscribed = \(isSubscribed)")
let userSubscriptionSetting = status.subscriptionStatus.userSubscriptionSetting
print("userSubscriptionSetting = \(userSubscriptionSetting)")
let userID = status.subscriptionStatus.userId
print("userID = \(userID)")
let pushToken = status.subscriptionStatus.pushToken
print("pushToken = \(pushToken)")
```

For Objective-C:

```
OSPermissionSubscriptionState* status = [OneSignal getPermissionSubscriptionState];
status.permissionStatus.hasPrompted
status.permissionStatus.status

status.subscriptionStatus.subscribed
status.subscriptionStatus.userSubscriptionSetting
status.subscriptionStatus.userId
status.subscriptionStatus.pushToken
```

So your above code will now look something like this:

```
let status: OSPermissionSubscriptionState = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState()

let userID = status.subscriptionStatus.userId
    print("userID = \(userID)")
let pushToken = status.subscriptionStatus.pushToken
    print("pushToken = \(pushToken)")

if pushToken != nil {
    if let playerID = userID {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered in the documentation, look like "userID" means "playerID".

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-native-sdk#section--getpermissionsubscriptionstate-

Answer (score 0):

`userId` is the same as the `playerId`, putting it all together in some sample Analytics (singleton) class I use in my Swift 4 app:

```
class Analytics : NSObject, OSSubscriptionObserver {

    ///the singleton
    static let shared = Analytics()


    func setupOneSignal(launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]?) {
        OneSignal.setLogLevel(.LL_VERBOSE, visualLevel: .LL_NONE)
        OneSignal.add(self as OSSubscriptionObserver)

        let settings : [String : Any] = [kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL : false]
        OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(
            launchOptions,
            appId:Environment.oneSignalAppId,
            handleNotificationReceived: {
                (osnotification) in
               //.....
        },
            handleNotificationAction: {
                (osNotificationOpenedResult) in
               //.....

        },
            settings: settings)
    }

    func onOSSubscriptionChanged(_ stateChanges: OSSubscriptionStateChanges!) {
        if  let state = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState(),
            let userId = state.subscriptionStatus.userId,
            let pushToken = state.subscriptionStatus.pushToken {
            print("onesignal.userId : \(userId)")
            print("onesignal.pushToken : \(pushToken)")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OSSubscriptionObserver {
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    OneSignal.addSubscriptionObserver(this);
  }
  
  public void onOSSubscriptionChanged(OSSubscriptionStateChanges stateChanges) {
    if (!stateChanges.getFrom().getSubscribed() &&
        stateChanges.getTo().getSubscribed()) {
         new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
             .setMessage("You've successfully subscribed to push notifications!")
             .show();
        // get player ID
        stateChanges.getTo().getUserId();
      }
   
      Log.i("Debug", "onOSSubscriptionChanged: " + stateChanges);
  }
}
```